# Session replication not working in Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, load-balancing, tomcat5.5, session-replication

There are 4 servers in the load balancer and Tomcat 5.5 is being used. The following points have been covered in setting up the Tomcat clustering, still the session replication is not happening properly.

1. Session attributes have implemented `java.io.Serializable`
2. Uncommented the `Cluster` element, `Valve(ReplicationValve)` element in server.xml
3. `Web.xml` has the `<distributable/>` element
4. `<Engine name="Catalina" jvmRoute="node01">`  set to unique values in all four servers.
5. `Loadbalancer` is configured for sticky session mode.

   ```
   <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
            managerClassName="org.apache.catalina.cluster.session.DeltaManager"
            expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
            useDirtyFlag="true"
            notifyListenersOnReplication="true">

       <Membership 
           className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.mcast.McastService"
           mcastAddr="228.0.0.4"
           mcastPort="45564"
           mcastFrequency="500"
           mcastDropTime="3000"/>

       <Receiver 
           className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.ReplicationListener"
           tcpListenAddress="auto"
           tcpListenPort="4001"
           tcpSelectorTimeout="100"
           tcpThreadCount="6"/>

       <Sender
           className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.ReplicationTransmitter"
           replicationMode="pooled"
           ackTimeout="15000"/>

       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.ReplicationValve"
              filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.txt;"/>

       <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                 tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                 deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                 watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                 watchEnabled="false"/>
   </Cluster>
   ```

Comment: Cheack all steps in [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html)

Comment: is step 5 necessary if you want to use session replication?

Comment: you want to say the sticky session part? well it is there in the docs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server configuration and would be more on topic on serverfault.